# habtm confusion.. Logical query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Book model and status of the book can be anything from NEW,
OLD, VERY_OLD. It can be NEW, OLD both or it could be both OLD and VERY_OLD. I want to
save user choices in a database. How would you suggest I implement this?

I could create a new model for Book condition but I feel that there must be a better way.

Comment: So are the options: 1) NEW, 2) OLD, 3) VERY_OLD, 4) NEW & OLD and 5) OLD & VERY_OLD ?

Comment: Do you want to be able to easily find books that are NEW, those that are OLD, those that are both NEW and OLD, for large data sets?

Comment: What do you mean save users choices in the database? Users make choices on the form, you decide how to store them.  Are you trying to amalgamate two properties here? New, Old and Very Old are ages, with condition, mint, tatty, or abused.

Comment: @GeorgeMillo. My options could be NEW, OLD, VERY_OLD, NEW & OLD, NEW & VERY_OLD, OLD & VERY_OLD.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson. Yes, you are right. In my case, users make choice on the form with the help of checkboxes and then I want to store those choices in database. User's options could be anyone of written above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, there are five possibilities for a book's status:

1. NEW
2. OLD
3. VERY_OLD
4. NEW & OLD
5. OLD & VERY_OLD

Assuming I've got that right, you could accomplish this with an [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). This would only require to add one new column to your DB, and wouldn't require a new model.

First add a `status` column if you haven't already got one:

```
# In a migration
add_column :books, :status, :integer
add_index :books, :status
```

(You might also want to add `null: false` to the line `add_column`, if you don't want it to be possible for a book to have **no** status.)

Then add this to your `Book` model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum status: [:new, :old, :very_old, :new_and_old, :old_and_very_old]

end
```

This generates methods on Book called `new?`, `old?`, `very_old?` etc. You might want to override these e.g. so `new?` returns true if status is `new_and_old` as well as just `new`:

```
def new?
  status == "new" || status == "new_and_old"
end
```

---

Another way to do this could be to add boolean columns to book called `new`, `old`, and `very_old`, but then this would require you to add a bunch of validations (e.g. to make sure that a book can't be both "new" and "very old".)

Comment: Okay. This seems fine. So, you mean that : Create an status column in books table and save values as "NEW", "OLD", "VERY_OLD", "NEW_OLD", "NEW_VERY_OLD", "OLD_VERY_OLD" in the status column of the books table. After that, create the enum in model(as you described). And override them just like :

    `def new?`
       `status == "NEW" || status == "NEW_OLD" || status == "NEW_VERY_OLD"`
    `end`

Comment: yes, except you should use lowercase values for your status names as that's a Rails/Ruby convention. So `enum status: [:new ... ]`, not `enum status: [:NEW ...]`. The first would define a method called `new?`, then second would define one called `NEW?` which isn't very conventional!

Comment: Aahaa. That's what I was looking for. :)